# How to Create Windows 7 Bootable DVD using Nero

Tags: boot, iso-image, nero

I have an .iso file that contains the windows 7 home edition and I want to make a bootable dvd to install it to my PC, I have nero burning rom 10. Is there any tutorial for this because I  found this: http://www.windowsvalley.com/how-to-create-windows-7-bootable-dvd-using-nero/ but it is explaining about .IMA files not .ISO files! is there any difference or its the same. Maybe I didnt understand the 3d step, do I have to choose the ISO file that I have?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the below screenshot matches what you see, you simply need to select the DVD-ROM (ISO) option in the sidebar on the left.

If the sidebar doesn't match what you see, I can't help you with Nero, as I don't use it. However, in that case you might try seeing the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download. Click "Show me how" at Step 2 ("Burn your CD or create a bootable USB stick").

[image: Screenshot from OP linked post]