# How to create a bootable dvd using nero startsmart essentials?

Tags: boot, dvd, nero

We want to create a bootable ubuntu 19.04 dvd. We are using nero startsmart essentials. We would like to know the steps. We are using nero 9 on windows 7 professional 32 bit.

We attempted to post it on [nero ag customer community](http://forum.nero.com/nero_eng) but could not register due to a technical error.

The sidebar does not match with the one mentioned in [the answer to the question, How to Create Windows 7 Bootable DVD using Nero](https://superuser.com/a/356122/1101159).

Comment: The ISO already has everything it needs to be bootable. Just burn it like you would any other image file.

Comment: https://neroknowhow.com/2016/05/10/how-can-i-create-and-burn-iso-images-with-nero-burning-rom/